# XML generation from service reference c# .net

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap

this is kinda related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680110/c-sharp-unmarshalling-error)

I have added a service reference to a project, just the standard way nothing fancy, and it has auto generated all the stuff for using the web service.

I have a c# project that uses the service reference and use the generated classes to construct the request.

When the xml request is generated and sent to the web service it appears that soap envelope is different/not correctly formed from what is expected by the web service.

I have hooked the wsdl up to SoapUI and compared the soap from Soap UI and my project.

My project generated soap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
   <openSession xmlns="http://autogenerated.OTWebServiceApi.xmbrace.com/">
    <openSession xmlns="">
     <id>0</id>
     <login>some login</login>
     <password>some password</password>
    </openSession>
   </openSession>
  </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

Soap Generated in SoapUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aut="http://autogenerated.OTWebServiceApi.xmbrace.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <aut:openSession>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <openSession>
             <id>0</id>
             <login>admin@fife</login>
             <password>admin1</password>
          </openSession>
       </aut:openSession>
    </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

So i guess my question is how do i get my project/service reference to generate the xml correctly?

Comment: Ok, looks like i am just gonna have to write the xml manually

Comment: Could you confirm that you can request the service from SoapUI without any problem? Becasuse both the XML examples are equal.

And have you tried to insert the first XML example to SoapUI and make a request?

Comment: Yea i can confirm that the request in soapUI works fine and when the first example is entered in SoapUI i get the same unmarshalling error as when it is run from my project. The first example has no soap:header

Comment: soap:header is not a required element according to the SOAP schema. So if it's empty, WCF has full right to omit it. So the header is not the case.

Comment: So after a while of testing i found that if i removed certain attributes related to namespaces in the code that was auto generated with the web reference i was able to request and receive responses from the web service